# Switching FXML files in BorderPane center part in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I tried to create a program in JavaFX which enables to show list of books and add new books.
I used a `BorderPane` as my main view and put a `ScrollPane` into the CENTEER part of `BorderPane`.
My `ScrollPane` contains `VBox` to which I add the list of another `FXML` files - separate `HBox` for each book ('book cards').

I have `BookCardController` with method `setCard`:

```
public class BookCardController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label bookAuthor;

    @FXML
    private HBox bookBox;

    @FXML
    private ImageView bookImage;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> bookList;

    private String[] statuses = {"Want to read", "Currently reading", "Read"};

    @FXML
    private Label bookTitle;

    public void setCard(Book book){
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(book.getImageSrc()));
        bookImage.setImage(image);
        bookTitle.setText(book.getTitle());
        bookAuthor.setText(book.getAuthor());
        bookList.setValue(statuses[book.getBookListId()]);

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        bookList.getItems().addAll(statuses);
    }
```

In my `MainController` class I created `setBookListView()` method which loads `BookCard.fxml` for each of the Books objects added to the list:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    VBox VBoxBooks = new VBox();

    @FXML
    BorderPane BorderPaneList;


    private List<Book> userBooks;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        setBookListView();
    }

    public void setBookListView() {
        userBooks = new ArrayList<>(addUserBooks());
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < userBooks.size(); i++) {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/BookCard.fxml"));
                HBox bookCard = loader.load();
                BookCardController bookCardController = loader.getController();
                bookCardController.setCard(userBooks.get(i));
                VBoxBooks.getChildren().add(bookCard);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It works great, but there is a problem.

I added a button which enables to add a new book. After clicking it, the center part of `BorderPane` changes to `FXML` file which contains a form for adding a new book with two buttons: 'save' and 'cancel'. My goal is to return to the previous view (`ScrollPane` with `VBox` containing all books cards) after clicking one of these buttons, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Here is my function which changes the center part of `BorderPane`:

```
public void setCenter(String fxmlPath){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
        parent = null;
        try {
            parent = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        BorderPaneList.setCenter(parent);
}
```

Here is my 'onAction' function for 'add new book' button:

```
public void switchToForm(ActionEvent event) {
        setCenter("/fxml/AddNewBook.fxml");
}
```

Here are my problematic 'onAction' functions for the two mentioned buttons:

```
public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        setBookListView();
    }

    public void cancel(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        setBookListView();
    }
```

My Main.java functions uses FXMLLoader to load my main BorderPane view (with empty scrollpane containing VBox).

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/BorderPaneList.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Better Reads");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

I tried switching scenes - I created two separate BorderPane fxml files - one with loading of list of book cards using mentioned function - `setBookListView()`, one with a form to add a new book.
I tried also calling a setBookListView() again in these two 'onAction' methods but it doesn't work.

There was an error which said that my `VBoxBooks.getChildren()` is a null but after its initialization, the error no longer appears. Currently the program works, list of books appears in a `ScrollPane` and after clicking 'add new book' button, the form appears but I can't do anything after that, because I don't know how to properly change the view to the previous one.

I don't know how should I correctly change the center part of `BorderPane` and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I suggest that you re-design your application to use a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE). By the way, [FXML] "controller" classes no longer need to implement `Initializable` interface. They can simply declare a `void initialize()` method, i.e. a method named `initialize` that has no [method] parameters and does not return a value.

Comment: A quick-ish workaround is to define a method in the controller like `public void setOnClosed(Runnable r) { this.onClosed = r;}`. Then the handlers for your ok and cancel buttons can do `if (onClosed != null) { onClosed.run(); }`. Now you can get the controller when you load the form and do `controller.setOnClosed(() -> { /* code to restore the view to the border pane */});`.

Comment: A more robust approach is to use a MVC-like design and model the current user state (i.e. what the user is looking at) in a presentation model. Then observe that state in the model and update the `BorderPane` accordingly when it changes. [Here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/bae73788a9b881cf9358cbf2d842f554) is a similar approach; it just changes the root of the scene when the current view changes but you can just as easily change the center of a border pane.